# wpf string formatting NOT numbers or dates

Tags: wpf, string, formatting

This should have a simple solution, but I can't seem to find it.

I want to do something like the following, where I have a data binding with a string format.  The field is a text field, and I'd like to display it with a suffix (but not change the underlying data).

```
<Label Name="field" Content="{Binding obj.field, StringFormat=\{0\} suffix}" />
```

So I want obj.field's value, for instance "value", to display as "value suffix".

Is it really necessary to use a ValueConverter (or whatever) to do this?  I'm thinking that if it's possible with the StringFormat construction, then there's some magic format option I just haven't encountered.

This leads to a related question: where can I find a reference for WPF StringFormat?  I can find the reference for the c# String.Format formatting options, but these don't all seem to work in WPF (like what I've tried above).

Comment: Any answers for the related question?

Comment: I must have accidentally removed my comment on the related question when I re-wrote my answer. I just updated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StringFormat` will work if the target type is `string`. However, the type of `Label`'s `Content` property is object. That is why the `StringFormat` has no effect. If you put a `TextBlock` inside the `Label` (or only use a `TextBlock`) and bind the `Textblock`'s `Text` property, it should work fine.

```
<Label>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding obj.field, StringFormat=\{0\} suffix}" />
</Label>
```

If you have other reasons to want to bind the value to the `Label`, you could also do the following.

```
<Label DataContext="{Binding obj.field}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ., StringFormat=\{0\} suffix}" />
</Label>
```

**Related question:** I can't think of any reason why normal format strings that you can supply to `string.Format()` wouldn't work. They all should, both the standard and custom string. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/05/19/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-stringformat.aspx) is a page with multiple examples. If there are any you find are not working, please provide examples.

Comment: Thanks.  I've become aware that labels are not "lite" TextBlocks, as I imagined, but another animal entirely.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Found a nice reference here with different examples : http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/